# get grayscale image from jpeg

Tags: python, jpeg, opencv

I have this jpeg image

[image]

I want to convert it to a grayscale image.
But when applaying

```
img = cv2.imread(filename)
grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I get this image, which is not a grayscale image ...

[image]

Why I didn't get a grayscale image ? How can I obtained it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're probably using `matplotlib` to display your image. When you do that, make sure you use a grey colormap. The default is `Viridis` (see docs), which is the blue-yellow colormap you're seeing

```
plt.imshow(grey_img, cmap = "gray")
plt.show()
```

As noted in the [`imshow` docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), pseudocolor will be added according to the colormap when you pass a 2D array:

> The input may either be actual RGB(A) data, or 2D scalar data, which will be rendered as a pseudocolor image. For displaying a grayscale image set up the colormapping using the parameters cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255.

Comment: Thanks for this explaination ! I was a little bit confuse because I used cv2.imshow() for previous show and it does not need this cmap precision.